# add machines and devices to MAAS with CLI

Tags: maas

I would like to pre-populate MAAS with new machines for future OS deployments.  For example, I have 10 servers, each with a quad port nic.  I know the MAC addresses (40) that belong to the servers (10), but don't know which MAC will get connected when the server is wired up.  How do I add these by script or CLI to MAAS.

Same question but for devices too. (routers, unmanaged hosts, etc.)

Currently, MAAS can discovery them, and I can add them to the database from the dashboard.  But this is time consuming, and has to be re-done everytime we trial out a new MAAS server.

Unless I am missing something, or the `--help` is incomplete, the CLI commands don't have add/create functions.

Seems odd to me that this command doesn't exist:

`maas <user> nodes create`

...so I am wondering if this is just not implemented yet, there is another way to handle this, or I am making a conceptual/workflow error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maas <user> nodes` is a read-only endpoint to read nodes. Nodes are a generic term for all Machines, Devices, and Controllers in MAAS. To be able to add a machine or device you must use the correct endpoint.

Add a machine:

`maas <user> machines create [params]...`

Add a device:

`maas <user> devices create [params]...`

Comment: Thank you.  Could you help me with what are the minimum parameters to add a machine using the CLI?  In the UI, we add a machine with a name, mac address, IPMI 2, IPMI ip address, username and password.   I can't seem to sort out the right parameters to automate this for new machines.

Comment: answered own question:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/939698/how-do-you-add-a-machine-to-maas-with-ipmi-power-using-cli