# What are the power parameters for MAAS when using Cisco UCS blades for machines

Tags: maas

I want to add Cisco UCS blades as new machines to my MAAS server.  What are the power parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
maas <maas_profile> machines create \
    mac_addresses=<new_machine_mac_address> \
    architecture=amd64 \
    hostname=<new_machine_name> \
    fqdn=<new_machine_fqdn> \
    power_type=ucsm \
    power_parameters_power_user=<ucs_username> \
    power_parameters_power_pass=<ucs_password> \
    power_parameters_uuid=<ucs_blade_uuid> \
    power_parameters_power_address=<ucs_url>
```

The UCS url is similar to the one you use for accessing UCS from the web browser.  However, it ends "/nuova".  For example, "http://my.ucs.server/nuova".  If you are using https, be ready for certificate issues.  If you have http and https enabled in UCS, but want MAAS to use http, you will need to disable http>https forwarding in the UCS console.

For additional information about the other parameters, see my other post at:

[How do you add a machine to MAAS with IPMI power using CLI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939698/how-do-you-add-a-machine-to-maas-with-ipmi-power-using-cli)