# maas node failed commisioning , failed to connect node via ssh

Tags: juju, maas

I setup MAAS server and configured images, networks, nodes and started commissioning.The nodes started POWERED ON, PXE booted successfully and in the console it is showing login prompt.From MAAS server it is still showing status as commissioning and after sometime it is showing commissioning failed'and maas.log showing timeout , i tried to login via ssh via public key but throwing connection refused.

HERE i didn't configured JUJU server to MAAS server , is this the reason for not connecting the node from maas server using maas public key

Answer (score 0):

MAAS doesn't require Juju.  And if commissioning failed, you wont be able to log in with the ssh key.

To create a working server using MAAS, there is a two part process.  First "Commission", then "Deploy".  If Commissioning succeeds, then you can deploy, and THEN you can log in with the SSH key.

Commissioning should result in a powered-off node.  So if the node is powered on and at a login prompt, you are probably seeing the previously-installed operating system.  This is a common outcome when PXE fails, the old OS boots, and commissioning fails (times out) after 20mins.

Commissioning is a three phase process 1) boot the node using IPMI or BMC mechanism, 2) Use PXE to load an ephemeral operating system for inspection/testing, 3) run hardware tests and take inventory.

Since you see the node turning on and booting to the PXE prompt, I think you are okay with #1.  My guess is #2 is failing -- even though it looks like it is succeeding.  When PXE works, it should work quickly, you should see a message that the boot files are being downloaded, there shouldn't be any errors, and you should clearly see a message "Booting under MAAS direction".

If PXE isn't working, you may need to adjust physical networking, or the subnet/DHCP configuration in MAAS.  If PXE is working, and commissioning is still failing, then you might have the wrong MAC address configured when you added the machine to MAAS.  Look at the links below for a few details.  If you have the wrong MAC (e.g. because you used the wrong physical port on the server), commissioning fails because MAAS doesn't know that the booting machine is the same machine as what you configured in MAAS.

[How do you add a machine to MAAS with IPMI power using CLI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939698/how-do-you-add-a-machine-to-maas-with-ipmi-power-using-cli)

[What are the power parameters for MAAS when using Cisco UCS blades for machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941623/what-are-the-power-parameters-for-maas-when-using-cisco-ucs-blades-for-machines)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Greetings,
I verified according to your reply as i completely format the SDD and check is there any booting happens from via HDD ,its not. Then I started 'POWRED ON' the server and observed that MAAS dhcp allocate ip address and got the message as 'Booting under MAAS direction' , further netboot happens and login prompt occurs with error message "Can not apply stage final, no datasource found! Likely bad things to come!" , there the issue with cloud-init scripts i think;  So are you aware of this , please reply back

Comment: It sounds like PXE is working, which is a good start.  PXE requires DHCP messages to reach the MAAS server and TFTP to reach the maas server to download the boot image.  But it sounds like, after the machine is booted, it can no longer reach the MAAS server.  Two possible causes are:  1) you might not have the correct ports open between the machines and MAAS to allow for the commissioning process to finish.  I suggest openning "IP/ANY" in both directions until you have a functioning deployment.  Then lock down firewall.   Next comment for #2...

Comment: 2) Does your MAAS server have multiple nics?  If you are using a management nic and another nic for DHCP in the target machine's network, you could see this problem.  This will cause an asymetric route during the commissioning process which, if you have a firewall between MAAS and the target machine, will get blocked.

Comment: Two other thoughts:  3) Possibly an IP conflict.  If your MAAS server has the same address as another server on your network, DHCP and initial PXE might work, both later communications will fail.  4) Are you using the latest version of MAAS?  Install MAAS using stable from PPA:  
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maas/stable`  Every version of MAAS has substantially less bugs than previous versions.

Comment: Thanks @james for reply,
Yes am using multiple nics one for **PXE/DHCP** and another for **external network** ,From **PXE/DHCP network**  , it is able to assign IP address , PXE booting happens and from **external network** we are able to send power control commands **(IPMI control)** am able to ping to the dhcp ip address from the maas server but ssh is not happening.
While booting node i observed **failed LSB bring up/down networking** on console, is it the issue???

Comment: We see lots of chatty false-positive "failed" messages on our node consoles during commissioning.  I don't think the error you mention is related.  I suspect its the nic and network configuration.  After the commissioned node boots into the ephemeral OS, the node calls home to maas -- hardwired to seek MAAS on MAAS's management nic.  But since MAAS has a second nic inside the network of the node, the reply packets will use the DHCP nic.     ...cont...

Comment: ...   This is different than your ping tests from MAAS, which leave via the DHCP nic and return to the DHCP nic.  So your MAAS traffic is asymetic -- which will fail if you have a firewall between MAAS mgmt nic and the node's network. We had this same problem in our initial deployment tests.    If you can, try testing by using only a single nic on MAAS and using a DHCP "helper" to get the nodes DHCP requests to jump subnets.